# What multithreading based data structure should I use?

Tags: multithreading, data-structures

I have recently come across a question based  on multi-threading. I was given a situation where there will be variable no of cars constantly changing there locations. Also there are multiple users who are posting requests to get location of any car at any moment. What would be data structure to handle this situation and why?

Comment: It is virtually impossible to give any useful answers without further information, especially about the higher-level operations to be implemented. For instance any requirement for consistency between multiple queries before committing a movement makes a big difference. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Is your question about some particular programming language or it is about general approaches how concurrency can be handled?

Comment: Let say its an online train running status tracker system. Where each train updates their location as last station passed. Also users make request to get current running status of any train to the system. New trains can also start running at any time. There are pre-implemented logics for this. I want to know how would I design such system so that there would be consistency between user's queries and train's current location.

Comment: @user3036938: Consistency between what precisely? It sort of sounds as if straightforward best-effort polling without any fancy synchronization would suffice here, just atomic read/writes operations with memory barriers. Note that, say, a train control system or one requiring efficient update notifications would require a vastly different solution.

Comment: Looks like you'll be fine with storing your state in any relational database that supports transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mutex (one per car).

Lock: before changing location of the associated car

Unlock: after changing location of the associated car

Lock: before getting location of the associated car

Unlock: after done doing work that relies on that location being up to date

Comment: May be you are right. But is that the conventional way to deal with such scenarios. Say it is a backend logic I want to implement. Would that be the best way to so?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you want your application to do

Comment: If you can add and remove cars, you'll need a lock on the overall data structure as well, because adding or removing a car affects more than just the car.

Answer (score 0):

I'd answer with:

Try to make threading an external concept to your system yet make the system as modular and encapsulated as possible at the same time. It will allow adding concurrency at later phase at low cost and in case the solution happens to work nicely in a single thread (say by making it event-loop-based) no time will have been burnt for nothing.

Comment: I don't actually get your point. How would you handle multiple user requests at the same time with a single thread.

Comment: One at a time, like server handling incoming requests. The question does not have enough details to speculate on what the best concurrency model suits best.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do this. Which way you choose depends a lot on the number of cars, the frequency of updates and position requests, the expected response time, and how accurate (up to date) you want the position reports to be.

The easiest way to handle this is with a simple mutex (lock) that allows only one thread at a time to access the data structure. Assuming you're using a dictionary or hash map, your code would look something like this:

```
Map Cars = new Map(...)
Mutex CarsMutex = new Mutex(...)

Location GetLocation(carKey)
{
    acquire mutex
    result = Cars[carKey].Location
    release mutex
    return result
}
```

You'd do that for Add, Remove, Update, etc. Any method that reads or updates the data structure would require that you acquire the mutex.

If the number of queries far outweighs the number of updates, then you can do better with a reader/writer lock instead of a mutex. With an RW lock, you can have an unlimited number of readers, OR you can have a single writer. With that, querying the data would be:

```
acquire reader lock
result = Cars[carKey].Location
release reader lock
return result
```

And Add, Update, and Remove would be:

```
acquire writer lock
do update
release writer lock
```

Many runtime libraries have a concurrent dictionary data structure already built in. .NET, for example, has `ConcurrentDictionary`. With those, you don't have to worry about explicitly synchronizing access with a Mutex or RW lock; the data structure handles synchronization for you, either with a technique similar to that shown above, or by implementing lock-free algorithms.

As mentioned in comments, a relational database can handle this type of thing quite easily and can scale to a very large number of requests. Modern relational databases, properly constructed and with sufficient hardware, are surprisingly fast and can handle huge amounts of data with very high throughput.

There are other, more involved, methods that can increase throughput in some situations depending on what you're trying to optimize. For example, if you're willing to have some latency in reported position, then you could have position requests served from a list that's updated once per minute (or once every five minutes). So position requests are fulfilled immediately with no lock required from a static copy of the list that's updated once per minute. Updates are queued and once per minute a new list is created by applying the updates to the old list, and the new list is made available for requests.

There are *many* different ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Downvoter, you have something to say? It's customary to give a reason for a downvote.